# Open Perspective in background from Eclipse Plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, perspective

I hava a piece of Code, that can only be executed, when a given perspective is already loaded/open.

I can use `PlatformUI.getWorkbench().showPerspective("perspectiveID",PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow());` (from a Gui-Thread) to forcefully show the Perspective, but that is not good manner.

I want to show a similiar Dialog to the "Do you want to open the Debug-Perspective now", but with the difference, that i allways *open* the Perspective, but only *bring it to the front*, if the user wishes to.

For completeness: This is the result of a user-context-menu click and the user might not know, what has happened to him when i change the perspective without him knowing. (The RCP-Application did not made use of perspectives before)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of investing much effort into the handling of awkward user interaction, please invest that effort into fixing the bug that your code can only be run when a certain perspective is opened.

There is no "opening a perspective, but not bringing it to the front" concept in Eclipse.

Comment: Sadly the bug does not resist in my code, but in another third-party extension, that my extension depends on.